# One build-agent for several repo

Tags: teamcity

I have 2 configurations in the teamcity which refer to 2 separate repositories in the mercurial. When starting a build  the project updates all its files. Can we configure 1 build agent to have 2 reprositories so that only the changes of the corresponding project are taken and not all files of the project at updated when starting the configuration? Or do we need to create 2 agents?

Comment: Build agents are not limited to a single project.

Comment: But why build agent always update my repo instead of save only changes?

Comment: Because your build configuration is configured to do that.

Comment: where it configure? help pls

Answer (score 0):

If TeamCity decided to clean checkout directory on an agent, it should log why this happens into the build log of the build.
Possible reasons of clean checkout are outlined in documentation: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Clean+Checkout